# How to compute sum of all the combinations of given list of numbers?

Tags: combinations

Suppose I have a list of numbers - A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,....,An.

How can I compute - `(A1*A2)+(A1*A3)+(A1*A4)+(A1*A5)+(A1*A6)+....`?

Ex-For 1,2,3 ,I need to calculate `1*2+2*3+1*3=11`.

Also generalize your solution for combinations containing more than 2 terms
Ex for three terms-`(A1*A2*A3)+(A1*A3*A4)+(A1*A4*A5)+(A2*A3*A4)+....`

Comment: You forgot to mention which programming language you will be using.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
def sumOfCombinations(l,s):
    return sum(prod(seq) for seq in (itertools.combinations(l, s)))

def prod(l):
    product = 1
    for x in l:
        product*=x
    return product

#exemple
myList = [1,2,3]
size = 2
print(sumOfCombinations(myList,size))
```

this would actually do the job in python. There are probably some more pythonic ways to accomplish this. But the results are there.